# a Small Line when exporting a Seamless texture

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, texture

Hi everyone this is my first post so im just gonna tell the problem here :
[image]

Everytime i export this image either in PNG or Jpeg Format theres always a Line on the box i dont know where it come from but when i open the file at my illustrator there's no line in my pattern, i tried searching it on google but found no solution (Maybe not alot of people experienced the same problem like mine).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution from a friend of a friend : when exporting there will be an option for Anti-Aliasing by defualt it was on "Type optimized" change it to "Art Optimized". i hope my answer solve some people problem when their having the same issues like me. (sry bad english)